# Concatenate drop down menus in HTML form with PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

What I would like to do is have more than one drop down menu in an HTML form and concatenate them so that the choices shown in the second menu are tied to the database element selected in the first menu. This is a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", NULL) or die("Connection Failed");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "tag-it")or die("Connection Failed"); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tipologie"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query); ?> 
    <select name="tipologia" onchange=""> 
    <?php while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $line['ID Tipologia'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Nome'];?> </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
    </select>
</div>
```

What it does right now is show all the rows I get from the database in the drop down, but what I want next is to show a second menu that gives me the choices based on the SQL relations and the selected element in the first menu. So I would like to use the option value field (which is a key in my DB) to perform another query and generate a second list. How can this be done? I was thinking of calling a PHP script from the onchange field of the select element, but wouldn't that reload the page?

Comment: AJAX, what you are looking for is AJAX

Comment: @Epodax, care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Look under the "Related" list, there's a bunch of questions that seek the same functionality.